# What is the current situation (2017) about triviality of $\phi^4$ theory in $d=3+1$?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, interactions, effective-field-theory, non-perturbative

I was reading a book by Franco Strocchi, [this one](https://books.google.it/books?id=C8prrhyON2kC&printsec=frontcover&dq=An%20Introduction%20to%20Non-Perturbative%20Foundations%20of%20Quantum%20Field%20Theory&hl=it&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=An%20Introduction%20to%20Non-Perturbative%20Foundations%20of%20Quantum%20Field%20Theory&f=false), and in some points the author claims that the case of $d=3+1$ of [triviality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_triviality) of $\phi^4$ theory is now proven. As far as I can tell, we have just some evidence from lattice computations. Am I missing any relevant reference about this matter?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by triviality?

Comment: Can you also add on what page this statement is made?

Comment: @DanielC You can find the statement on page 38 starting with "The recent proof of triviality...".

Comment: @Prahar A simple presentation of triviality is given at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_triviality. My preferred one uses the form of the propagator that is Yukawa-like or a sum of Yukawas and all the part of the spectrum with bound states just missing considering a Källén-Lehmann representation.

Comment: @prahar  Triviality in this context means that the continuum limit of the lattice theory only exists for the free theory.

Answer (score 2):

Michael Aizenman and Hugo Duminil-Copin announced last year a proof that the scaling limit of lattice $\phi^4$ theory in 4d is trivial.  It's been known since the 80s that the scaling limit is Gaussian up to logarithmic corrections for small coupling ([work](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.cmp/1104116964) of Feldman, Magnen, Rivasseau, & Seneor).  Aizenman & Duminil-Copin found a method which works without restriction on the interaction and field size.

Their [preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.07973) appeared on the arxiv in December.  I don't think it's been formally published yet, but the argument isn't that hard to follow.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is similar to the one seen on Mathoverflow but I am mot able to find it now. Surely, after the publication of Aizenman's and Duminil-Copin's paper, the matter will be settled. Anyway, I think that Strocchi's sentence was relying just on lattice computations but these are not a real mathematical proof.