# $\phi^4$ theory in higher dimensions

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, renormalization, dimensional-analysis

For a scalar, the Lagrangian $$L = \partial_{\mu}\phi\partial^{\mu}\phi - m^2\phi^2 + \lambda \phi^4$$ seems to be particularly suited for 4 dimensional space-time. In four dimensions, the coupling constant, $\lambda$, ends up being dimensionless, and the theory is renormalizable. How does the interaction Lagrangian $\lambda \phi^4$ get modified for higher dimensions? Does it become $\lambda\phi^n$ in n-dimensions? Is the $\phi^4$ theory or $\phi^n$ theory renormalizable in higher dimensions?
Also, any literature reference would also be helpful.

Comment: It's highly likely that $\phi^4$ theory doesn't exists in four dimensions (I hope it exists), because renormalization group appears to make it go trivial (lambda goes to zero). In higher dimensions, there are some proofs about triviality of that theory ($\phi^4$) in more than 4 dimensions. Until recent times it was believed that in higher dimensions there were no non-trivial quantum theories because of naive renormalization group arguments, but there is some evidence that at least the (2,0) superconformal field theories are possible to get by means of a modified version of super-yang-mills.

Comment: @Uli_WH  There's a mathematical proof now that $\phi^4$ does not exist in 4 dimensions.  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/364576/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $D$ be the spacetime dimension. The action is dimensionless for any $D$ (since the action has units of $\hbar$, and we set $\hbar=1$)., Since $S = \int {\rm d}^D x \mathcal{L}$, and the volume element  ${\rm d}^D x$ has mass dimension $-D$, this means the Lagrangian $\mathcal{L}$ has dimension $D$

Assuming we have a weakly coupled scalar field theory, the scaling dimension of the field $\phi$ will be determined by the kinetic term, $\mathcal{L} \sim (\partial \phi)^2$ (if you like, in the free theory only the kinetic term and maybe mass term are there, so in the free theory these determine the scaling of the field, and then perturbative quantum corrections will only lead to small changes to the free theory mass dimension). Since derivatives have mass dimension $1$ in any dimension, and the Lagrangian has mass dimension $D$, in order for things to work, the field must have dimensions $(D-2)/2$. You can check that in $D=4$, this works out to say that the field should have dimension $1$, which is the case.

Then we can consider a general operator (term in the Lagrangian) of the form
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L} \sim \lambda \partial^{n_d} \phi^{n_\phi}
\end{equation}
where $\lambda$ is a (possibly dimensionful) coupling constant; $n_d$ is the number of derivatives; and $n_\phi$ is the number of powers of $\phi$. Then the dimension of $\lambda$ is
\begin{equation}
\Delta_\lambda = D - n_d - n_\phi \frac{D-2}{2} = D + \left(1-\frac{D}{2}\right)n_\phi - n_d
\end{equation}

For $D=4, n_\phi=4, n_d=0$, this yields $\Delta_\lambda=0$, as you expect.

For an arbitrary $D$, with $n_\phi=4, n_d=0$, we have
\begin{equation}
\Delta_\lambda = 4 - D
\end{equation}
which is negative for all $D>4$; in other words, $\phi^4$ theory is power-counting non-renormalizable for all $D>4$.

Since we set up the formalism, we might as well look at a general interaction. Let's set $n_d=0$. Then the expression is
\begin{equation}
\Delta_\lambda =  D + \left(1-\frac{D}{2}\right)n_\phi
\end{equation}
Then...

- For $D=1$, this is always positive.
- For $D=2$, the mass dimension is always $2$ for any operator. (2 dimensions is special in many ways).
- For $D=3$, this simplifies to $\Delta_\lambda = 3 - \frac{n_\phi}{2}$, which is only nonegative if $n_\phi \leq 6$. Therefore, $\phi^6$ theory is dimensionless in three dimensions. Higher powers of $\phi$ are nonrenormalizable.
- For $D=4$, this becomes $\Delta_\lambda = 4 - n_\phi$, so only $\phi^3$ and $\phi^4$ theories are renormalizable.
- For $D=5$, this becomes $\Delta_\lambda = 5 - \frac{3 n_\phi}{2}$, so only $\phi^3$ is renormalizable.
- For $D=6$, we have $\Delta_\lambda = 6 - 2 n_\phi$, so $\phi^3$ is dimensionless (and therefore analogous to $\phi^4$ theory in $4$ dimensions). This is the theory that Srednicki bases the first third of his textbook on.
- For $D \geq 7$, all terms with $n_\phi \geq 3$ have negative mass dimension, and so are not renormalizable.

Since $n_d$ contributes negatively to $\Delta_\lambda$, any interactions with derivatives can only possibly be renormalizable if the derivative-less version is.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, does it mean that any scalar self interaction is impossible beyond 7 dimensions? Supersymmetry, string theory, all deal with dimensions greater than 7.

Comment: @Angela You would think so :) The short answer is "no," but the explanation is not short. For a single scalar field, it is indeed true that beyond $7$ dimensions there are no perturbatively renormalizable theories (and no *stable* renormalizable theories beyond $D=4$, since a $\phi^3$ potential is unbounded below). But there are several magic things that can happen. First, even non-renormalizable theories are ok as effective low-energy approximations of deeper theories. Second, non-perturbatively the scheme I laid out need not hold -- a deeper analysis would use

Comment: the renormalization group and ask about the scaling behavior near fixed points in the flow; I've essentially assumed a particular kind of fixed point called a "trivial" fixed point. Third, supersymmetry does a lot to cancel naive divergences and cure some problems that apparently simpler theories have. Finally, string theory essentially has an infinite number of fields, and which also enables various kinds of magic. More to the point, in perturbative string theory, the conformal invariance on the worldsheet relates the high and low energy behavior, and cures UV divergences.

Comment: There's not really a simple summary except to say... for straightforward scalar field theories, you are very limited in what you can do if you want something perturbatively renormalizable. If you want to "jump into the deep end" with string theory, super symmetry, conformal symmetry, and the non-perturbative renormalization group, the story is vastly more complex.